# Jquery-ui append div on drop and make appended div droppable(nested)

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable, jquery-append

I need to drag one element and while dropping it should append a new html div container and appended html div container should be droppable (nested). I have attached fiddle file here. Can any one help on this?

```
$('.dragItem').draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  connectToSortable: "#column2,#column2 div"
});

$('.dragItem').sortable({
  containment: "parent"
});

$('#column2').sortable({
  placeholder: "highlight"
});

$('#column2').droppable({
  accept: '.dragItem',
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var draggable = ui.draggable;

    var droppable = $(this);
    var drag = $('#column2').has(ui.draggable).length ? draggable : draggable.clone().draggable({});
    drag.appendTo(column2); 
    drag.sortable({
      placeholder: "highlight"
    });
    drag.droppable({
      accept: ".dragItem",
      drop: function (event, ui) {
        var draggable = ui.draggable;
        var droppable = $(this);
        var drag = $('#column2').has(ui.draggable).length ? draggable : draggable.clone().draggable({});
      }
    })
    drag.css({width:'', height: ''})
  }
});`
```

[Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pushparaj_graspio/7sLfsdg9/)

Comment: I am concerned with 2 elements both having sortable and droppable. I believe this would create a conflict. Are you attempting to create a nested droppable div where it's parent can be sorted?

Comment: I looked at your fiddle, and I can drag and drop into either. I can also drag and drop into the nested items, repeatedly. So I am not sure what is not working.

Comment: Yeah nested is working but i need to append html template(divs with styles) while dropping and make that dropped divs as droppable.

Comment: While dropping new div containers should append and need to make that dropped new container as droppable (nested).Appending new html while dropping and making that as droppable is the problem .

Comment: Ok what html needs to appended?

Comment: Nested drop is done.while dropping drop two box(box1,box2)one below other and second box(box2) should be nested droppable.I have to append only two boxes and second box as droppable.Thanks in advance

Comment: $template=$("<div class="static">box1</div><div class="droppable-box-nested">box2</div>");  want to append this template while dropping